# reading csv columns dynamically in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: csv, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

If I have a Table Input step with a query such as `Select * from myTable`
and it goes to a User Defined Java Class step, the following code allows me to grab the column names dynamically from the table.

`RowMetaInterface rowMetaInterface = getInputRowMeta();`
`List myList = rowMetaInterface.getValueMetaList();`
`String colName;`

`for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){`
`colName = ((ValueMetaInterface)myList.get(i)).getName();`
`}`

However, this code doesn't work if the first step is a CSV input step.  I have a variable for the CSV filename, so I can't do a 'Get Fields' to pull the columns. Is there a way I can read the csv column names dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but some interesting hints:
http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2015/10/31/Transformation-Executor-Record-Groups.html